# How can I go from blog.example.com to example.com/blog

Tags: seo

I read this:

> This is one of the major reasons why SEOs advise clients to put blogs
>   on example.com/blog rather than blog.example.com

But I have  http://example.com served by my server and http://blog.example.com for a blog hosted on Googles blogspot.com so how can i do this because the two parts are served by two seperate server, doesnt each server need its own (sub)domain ?

I also have some pages stored on Amazon S3 so these are accessed via http://static.example.com

Answer (score 1):

So, first off, I just want to say that while it is important for SEO (and conversion optimization as well) to consolidate your content onto a single domain, it isn't like you absolutely have to do this or else Google won't rank your site. My advice to clients in this spot is to evaluate the business case carefully - would you have such a gain in traffic from search (or in sales) as a result of this change that it is worth the technical challenges to consolidate domains? Or, might you be better off investing that money/time/energy in promoting the sites you currently have instead of investing that money/time/energy in the technical change?

So, now, as for how you handle this situation, you would need to move your blog to the same server that hosts the rest of your content. Same goes for the content on static.example.com. For the blog, that would require moving to a blogging platform that works with your server setup, transferring over content, and redirecting URLs from your current blog to your new blog.

Depending on how many posts you have, that could be a minor project or a massive undertaking. I'd evaluate the business case on that carefully and the projected impact this move could have before committing to this especially if it is going to be a pretty massive undertaking.

Comment: Right so to confirm they have to be on the same machine if use the form http://domain/page. Its certainly not worth my while moving the blog, but maybe its worth having a page on my site with a link to each blogpost though, actually regarding static.example.com could I hide the difference via Amazon cloudfront ?

Comment: Actually I don't really get why they are treated differently because you can only use a subdomain if  you own the domain so why not treat as the same ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor - agreed to an extent. There are instances where this isn't true that you own the root domain (Squarespace for instance). To be sure, Google has made strides toward supporting subdomains, but still you are better off with all content on one vs. subs but not a make or break deal usually. 

I would definitely add in cross links and match up the design. Also, you can explore using an alias or proxy. Check out this thread for details about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019328/sub-directory-to-a-different-server